# Не работает переадресация в node.js

Tags: html, node.js

У меня есть проект, есть авторизация. После заполнения формы данные отправляются методом get. Когда данные не совпадают с данными на базе всё происходит так, как я задумал. Но когда данные заполняются правильно не происходит редирект и страница просто очень долго грузится и в конце пишет что страница не отвечает. На серверной стороне же я не вижу проблем в терминале.

Вот участок кода:

```js
checklogin(false)

app.get("/about", function (request, response) {
    let log = request.query.login;
    let pass = request.query.password;
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i].login == log & data[i].pass == pass) {
                console.log('Succes login');
                checklogin(true, data[i].login, data[i].pass)
                i = data.length
                break
            } else if (i == data.length - 1) {
                let rtext = `Неправильный логин или пароль`
                response.send(rtext)
            }
        }
});

function checklogin(b, l, p) {
    if (b === true) {
        console.log(`login=${l}&password=${p}`)
        app.get(`/about?login=${l}&password=${p}`, function (request, response){
            console.log('ss');
            return response.redirect("/panel")
            
        })
    }
    if (b === false) {
        app.use("/panel", function (request, response) {
            console.log("ok, false");
            return response.redirect("/login")
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Попробуйте еще установить статус после редиректа.

Comment: Условие работает, проверил через console.log, сейчас попробуй установить статус

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте принять get параметры через `request.query`

```
app.get('/about', function(request,response) {
  let login = request.query.login;
  let pass = request.query.pass;
  //сравнение в свашими значениями
  //if () {...}  
  return response.redirect('/panel');
})
```

Comment: я так делаю, если данные совпали с данными на базе данных то вызываю функцию checklogin(), и передаю туда логин и пароль(l, p)

Comment: почему-то, когда я решил попробовать сделать console.log("login=${l}&password=${p}") я получаю login=${l}&password=${p}

Comment: оберните в `` (обратные) кавычки весь запрос

Comment: ой точно, большое спасибо, совсем про это забыл)

Comment: но переадресация всё равно не работает...

Comment: о, помогло return response.redirect('/panel'), надо было сразу там это делать... спасибо